# Java-FX How to set image in a GridPane on click - game Othello

Tags: image, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, gridpane

Hi i'm trying to click on a position (from 0 to 7) in my GridPane.
I would set an image inside it. I tryed everything but i can't see any improvement...

This is my board
[image]

Here my code on click on grid

```
@FXML
   private void clickGrid(MouseEvent event) {
      myGrid = new GridPane();
      black = new Image("othello/images/black.png");
      white = new Image("othello/images/white.png");
      empty = new Image("othello/images/empty.png");

      Node source = (Node)event.getSource() ;
      Integer colIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(source);
      Integer rowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(source);
      System.out.printf("Mouse clicked cell [%d, %d]%n", colIndex.intValue(), rowIndex.intValue());

      myGrid.add(new ImageView(white), colIndex, rowIndex);

   }
```

Here my code when i click restart

```
 @FXML
   private void restartGame(ActionEvent event)throws Exception{
      myGrid = new GridPane();
      black = new Image("othello/images/black.png");
      white = new Image("othello/images/white.png");
      empty = new Image("othello/images/empty.png");
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){ //Per righe
      for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){ // Per colonne
      myGrid.add(new ImageView(empty), i, j);
      }

      }
      myGrid.add(new ImageView(black), 3, 3);
      myGrid.add(new ImageView(black), 4, 3);
      myGrid.add(new ImageView(white), 4, 4);
      myGrid.add(new ImageView(white), 4, 3);
   }
```

black is my piece colored of black, for white is white.

Source path

```
I have main project in src of netbeans.
Inside it, i have:
- othello (it contains my main)
- othello.images (it cointains all my image also backgrounds)
- othello.view (it contains my FXML files)
- othello.model (now nothing)
- othello.controller (it contains the controllers about the fxml files)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a new GridPane on every click:

```
myGrid = new GridPane(); // delete this
```

delete this line, and add an image to the GridPane you've prepared in FXML

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't see new images because you add to a new Grid, not to the existent one:

```
myGrid = new GridPane();  // !!! here a problem
myGrid.add(new ImageView(white), colIndex, rowIndex);
```